# Buttons in select menu are not responding?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

When trying to create a verification/gender verification, I encountered a problem where when I tried to click the button, an error popped up.

```
class verify(discord.ui.View):

    @discord.ui.select(
        placeholder="Choose an option",
        options=[
            discord.SelectOption(label="Men", value="1", emoji=""),
            discord.SelectOption(label="Girl", value="2", emoji=""),
            discord.SelectOption(label="Undefined", value="3", emoji="")
        ]
    )

    async def select_callback(self, select, interaction: discord.Integration):
        select.disabled=True
        if select.value[0] == "1":
            await interaction.response.send_message("You choose Men!")
        if select.value[0] == "2":
            await interaction.response.send_message("You choose Girl!")
        if select.value[0] == "3":
            await interaction.response.send_message("You choose Undefined!")

 


@client.command(name="setgender")
async def setgender(ctx):
    await ctx.send(view=verify())
```

When he tries to use any of the buttons. Discord is telling me "This action failed". I don't know what to do right now.

Comment: Welcome to SO! You keep talking about buttons, but the code shown is for a select menu. Where are the buttons you are talking about? Are there any error messages in the console at all when you press these buttons?

Comment: Maybe I worded the question wrong, I meant selectOptions. And to answer your question, nothing pops up in the console when clicking. And on discord he still shows what is in the picture. (https://imgur.com/a/qrFN2Sz)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so the issue you're encountering is because your code is throwing an error and therefore not responding. You're probably getting a `AttributeError: 'Select' object has no attribute 'value'`.

```py
class Verify(discord.ui.View):
    @discord.ui.select(
        placeholder="Choose an option",
        options=[
            discord.SelectOption(label="Men", value="1", emoji=""),
            discord.SelectOption(label="Girl", value="2", emoji=""),
            discord.SelectOption(label="Undefined", value="3", emoji="")
        ]
    )
    async def select_callback(self, select, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        select.disabled = True
        value = select.values[0]
        if value == "1":
            await interaction.response.send_message("You choose Men!")
        elif value == "2":
            await interaction.response.send_message("You choose Girl!")
        elif value == "3":
            await interaction.response.send_message("You choose Undefined!")
```

It's `select.values` and not `select.value`. Additionally, the type hint for `interaction` was wrong - should be `discord.Interaction` and *not* `discord.Integration`.

Also, when you do `select.disabled = True`. This isn't doing anything on it's own. You either need to update the original message or just delete it. I would probably delete it. Either way, code for doing that is below.

```py
class Verify(discord.ui.View):
    @discord.ui.select(
        placeholder="Choose an option",
        options=[
            discord.SelectOption(label="Men", value="1", emoji=""),
            discord.SelectOption(label="Girl", value="2", emoji=""),
            discord.SelectOption(label="Undefined", value="3", emoji="")
        ]
    )
    async def select_callback(self, select, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        select.disabled = True
        value = select.values[0]
        if value == "1":
            await interaction.response.send_message("You choose Men!")
        elif value == "2":
            await interaction.response.send_message("You choose Girl!")
        elif value == "3":
            await interaction.response.send_message("You choose Undefined!")
        
        # do either one of these by uncommenting one
        # await interaction.message.delete()
        # await interaction.message.edit(view=self)
```

Hope that helps.